# How can I create an animation class to use in other activities in android?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-activity

I have this animation activity for falling images. It works perfectly. What I would like to is change this, so I can call something like, startImageFallAnimation(), in another activity, and have it show over the current activity. I'd hate to have to add all this code to every activity I want to use it in. I experimented for a few hours, with no luck.

How can I accomplish this?

```
import com.tmp.animation.R;

public class FallAnimationActivity extends Activity {

// 100 = lots falling / 1000 = less falling
public int imageInterval = 100;

private int[] LEAVES = { 
        R.drawable.coin,
        R.drawable.starsm,
        //R.drawable.leaf_yellow,
        //R.drawable.leaf_other,
    };

private Rect mDisplaySize = new Rect();

private RelativeLayout mRootLayout;
private ArrayList<View> mAllImageViews = new ArrayList<View>();

private float mScale;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    display.getRectSize(mDisplaySize);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    mScale = metrics.density;

    mRootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    new Timer().schedule(new ExeTimerTask(), 0, imageInterval);
}

public void create() {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getRectSize(mDisplaySize);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    mScale = metrics.density;

    mRootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    new Timer().schedule(new ExeTimerTask(), 0, imageInterval);
}


public void startAnimation(final ImageView aniView) {

    aniView.setPivotX(aniView.getWidth()/2);
    aniView.setPivotY(aniView.getHeight()/2);

    long delay = new Random().nextInt(Constants.MAX_DELAY);

    final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    animator.setDuration(Constants.ANIM_DURATION);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setStartDelay(delay);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        int angle = 50 + (int)(Math.random() * 101);
        int movex = new Random().nextInt(mDisplaySize.right);

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();

            aniView.setRotation(angle*value);
            aniView.setTranslationX((movex-40)*value);
            aniView.setTranslationY((mDisplaySize.bottom + (150*mScale))*value);
        }
    });

    animator.start();
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        int viewId = new Random().nextInt(LEAVES.length);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(LEAVES[viewId]);
        LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(FallAnimationActivity.this);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflate.inflate(R.layout.ani_image_view, null);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        mRootLayout.addView(imageView);

        mAllImageViews.add(imageView);          

        LayoutParams animationLayout = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        animationLayout.setMargins(0, (int)(-150*mScale), 0, 0);
        animationLayout.width = (int) (60*mScale);
        animationLayout.height = (int) (60*mScale);

        startAnimation(imageView);
    }
};

private class ExeTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // we don't really use the message 'what' but we have to specify something.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.EMPTY_MESSAGE_WHAT);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT- After lots of work, this is the best I've got, but I cant solve passing context into the handler, or passing the layout into the first method.

```
import com.tmp.animation.R;


public class FallPop {

private static final String TAG = FallPop.class.toString();

private static final FallPop INSTANCE = new FallPop();

private int[] LEAVES = {
        R.drawable.leaf_green,
        R.drawable.leaf_red,
        R.drawable.leaf_yellow,
        R.drawable.leaf_other,
};

private Rect mDisplaySize = new Rect();

private RelativeLayout mRootLayout;
private ArrayList<View> mAllImageViews = new ArrayList<View>();

private float mScale;


private FallPop(){

}

public static FallPop getInstance() {

    return INSTANCE;
}

public Context context;

public Context context2;

int count = 0;

public void doAnim(Context context){

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getRectSize(mDisplaySize);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    mScale = metrics.density;

    // FIX!!!
   // mRootLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    new Timer().schedule(new ExeTimerTask(), 0, 200);

}

public void startAnimation(final ImageView aniView) {

    aniView.setPivotX(aniView.getWidth()/2);
    aniView.setPivotY(aniView.getHeight()/2);

    long delay = new Random().nextInt(Constants.MAX_DELAY);

    final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    animator.setDuration(Constants.ANIM_DURATION);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setStartDelay(delay);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        int angle = 50 + (int)(Math.random() * 101);
        int movex = new Random().nextInt(mDisplaySize.right);

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();

            aniView.setRotation(angle*value);
            aniView.setTranslationX((movex-40)*value);
            aniView.setTranslationY((mDisplaySize.bottom + (150*mScale))*value);
        }
    });

    animator.start();
}



Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            int viewId = new Random().nextInt(LEAVES.length);

            // Need some context here                 \/
            Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, LEAVES[viewId]);
            // Original line, also didnt work \/
            //Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(LEAVES[viewId]);

            LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) inflate.inflate(R.layout.ani_image_view, null);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
            mRootLayout.addView(imageView);

            mAllImageViews.add(imageView);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams animationLayout = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
            animationLayout.setMargins(0, (int) (-150 * mScale), 0, 0);
            animationLayout.width = (int) (60 * mScale);
            animationLayout.height = (int) (60 * mScale);

            startAnimation(imageView);
        }
    };





class ExeTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // we don't really use the message 'what' but we have to specify something.
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Constants.EMPTY_MESSAGE_WHAT);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: do not extend it to activity. Make it simple java class with static methods.

Comment: put your animation code in a utility class and then just pass the imageview. Make sure your utility class does not live longer than lifeycle of activity or else you risk memory leaks

Comment: U should create separate utils class i.e animation utils to keep the things separate.

Comment: When I start making the methods static, lots of lines start erroring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Java class with static method startImageFallAnimation(),where you will write all your animation code and just call the method wherever it is required

Comment: This seems like the way to go, and definitely what I need. I want to be able to call this animation with a single line. But the activity I mentioned above is, of course, an activity. Im having trouble changing it to a class. Especially with everything coded, triggering from a single method call

Comment: Try creating a animationutils class which won't extend any activity or so,and include a static method called startImageFallanimation which will take imageview as a parameter as you want to animate an imageview. On the other side let the other class in which you want to use animation extend an activity and just call animationutils class method startImageFallanimation at place where you want to apply animation.

Comment: What if you create a subclass which extends Handler? That way you could pass any parameters you want.

Comment: I read that elsewhere. So how would I call and receive the handler then in reference to starting the animation then?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution I can think of would be to make the target `Activities` extend this class and change the access level of the member variables in `FallAnimationActivity` to 'protected'. Depending on whether you need this in all/most `Activities`, I'd put the logic in a base class.

Comment: Im sorry, I just can't seem to understand quite what you mean. In before, "go learn basic Java first!" im learning as I go, and Thats worked out wonderfully until this.

Answer (score 0):

have context as a parameter in your util class

example:

```
public animation(Imageview imageview, Context mContext)
{
Animation slideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.slide_out_left);
 imageview.startAnimation(slideLeft);
}
```

then in the activity you want to call it in do

```
// for activity
Utils.animation(Your image view, this)

//for fragment
Utils.animation(Your image view, getContext)
```

my utility class is called Utils, so you type whatever you named the class and call the method accordingly